# Pandas groupby - Find mean of first 10 items

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 30 items in each group.

To find mean of entire items, I use this code.

```
y = df[["Value", "Date"]].groupby("Date").mean()
```

That returns a value like this.

```
Date                  Value
       
2020-01-01 00:30:00   7172.36
2020-01-01 01:00:00   7171.55
2020-01-01 01:30:00   7205.90
2020-01-01 02:00:00   7210.24
2020-01-01 02:30:00   7221.50
```

However, I would like to find the mean of the first 10 items in the group instead of the entire items.

```
y1 = df[["Value", "Date"]].groupby("Date").head(10).mean()
```

That code return only a single `Value` instead of a pandas series.

So I'm getting errors like this.

`AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'`

What is the proper way to get the pandas series instead of a single value?

Comment: Don't `groupby`: `df['Value'].head(10).mean()`

Comment: @mozway Would that only return the first 10 item mean from each group?

Comment: No, in this case use `apply` and slice **inside** it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
y1 = df[["Value", "Date"]].groupby("Date").apply(lambda g: g['Value'].head(10).mean())
```

```
print(y1)

Date
2020-01-01 00:30:00    7172.36
2020-01-01 01:00:00    7171.55
2020-01-01 01:30:00    7205.90
2020-01-01 02:00:00    7210.24
2020-01-01 02:30:00    7221.50
dtype: float64
```

In `.groupby("Date").head(10).mean()`, `groupby.head()` returns the DataFrame, `.mean()` is operated on the whole DataFrame rather than the group.

Comment: It does not return the column name. Any idea why?

Comment: @John `g['Value']` select the Series, if you want column name, you can try `g[['Value']]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
# slice the first 10 and average
y1 = df.groupby("Date")["Value"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:10].mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution when tackling the same issue. However my DataFrame was pretty big, so I noticed that just `df.groupby().apply()` was pretty slow and the `df.groupby().head(N).groupby().mean()` solution detailed below a bit faster.

**Set up data and imports**
First, assuming you (only) have values every 30 minutes we can create a big array to test this out.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

dts =  pd.date_range('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', '2020-01-31T23:30:00Z',freq='30T')
limit = len(dts)*50
indices = np.random.choice(len(dts), limit)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
                       'Date':dts[indices], 
                       'Value':np.random.random_integers(100,high=100_000,size=limit)/50
                       },
                 )
```

`df` is now something like (with random values in 'Value' column)

```
                       Date    Value
0 2020-01-08 08:00:00+00:00  1332.52
1 2020-01-21 19:30:00+00:00  1729.46
2 2020-01-22 01:00:00+00:00  1418.68
3 2020-01-16 05:00:00+00:00    95.10
4 2020-01-02 13:30:00+00:00  1878.30
.                       ...      ...
.                       ...      ...
.                       ...      ...
and so on
```

**Solution 1**
Here we run an apply over each group, take the first 10 values, and calculate mean from them. Somehow this is slower than solution 2. It returns a Pandas Series.

```
y1 = df[["Value", "Date"]].groupby("Date").apply(lambda g: g['Value'].head(10).mean())
```

Timing with `%%timeit -n 10`

```
287 ms ± 4.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Solution 2**
In solution 2 we first groupby date and take the 10 first, and then another groupby on date and then mean. It returns a Pandas DataFrame.

```
y2 = df[["Value", "Date"]].groupby("Date").head(10).groupby("Date").mean()
```

Timing

```
9.79 ms ± 848 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Conclusion**

Of course both solutions give the same results

```
np.allclose(y1.values, y2.Value.values)
```

only, solution 2 is (depending on shape of input and complexity of operation) almost 30x faster.

Tested in Python 3.8.13, Pandas 1.4.4, and Numpy 1.18.5, on a 32 core Intel Xeon server through Jupyter Lab.